# How much clearance is needed on a gas fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

I have a small gas fireplace already installed.  I cut a hole in side and it looks like it has about a foot clearance (opening between the outer wall and fireplace housing).  In addition, it looks like there is 16 inches above the top for the fireplace and the bottom of the mantle.

I would like to reduce the clearance to 14 or 12 inches and wanted to know what is the correct clearance.  Additionally, I wanted to check if any mantel shield would be recommended as I would like to put a wood mantle on top.

Comment: Any idea what make/model fireplace it is?  The clearances should be in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You should try to determine the manufacturer and model of your fireplace and get a copy of the installation instructions, which will have detailed instructions on the required clearances.    The answer will vary depending on the construction of the fireplace.