# Required safe distance from wood fireplace?

Tags: code-compliance, fireplace, fire-hazard

What is the minimum safe distance to install permanent fixtures (cabinets) next to a fireplace?
Fireplace is open on 2 sides: front and right side, facing the future fixture.
Unit is in multi family building.
I understand local fire code may apply. 2012 IBC is what applies locally forconstruction.

Is 3 ft distance enough?
Would closing the side of the fireplace help lower risk?

Comment: There is no 'may' about it, must follow local codes.  What the cabinets are made of will affect distance and if you place a heat shield between.  Modifying the fireplace also needs permits.  Your local fire department will be happy to come and give you ideas as to what you can do for code(probably even for free).

Comment: "Combustible material within **12 inches** (306 mm) of the fireplace opening shall not project more than 1/8 inch (3.2 mm) for each 1-inch (25.4 mm) distance from such an opening."

Comment: [How much clearance is needed on a gas fireplace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41172/how-much-clearance-is-needed-on-a-gas-fireplace)